# Changing a path drawn in a canvas to an image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Currently I have a circle in my canvas, and the circle follows the mouse around. The canvas updates periodically, so that the old circles are erased so it gives the impression that there is one circle that follows the mouse around. I did this using the setMousePosition function. The function is called in the update function that looks like this

```
function update() {


    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(mouseX, mouseY, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
    context.clip();

    var img = new Image()
    img.addEventListener("load", function(e) {
        context.fillStyle = context.createPattern(this, "no-repeat")
        context.fill()
        }, true);
        img.src="pics/iris.jpg"

    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
update();
```

As you can see, img is sourced at pics/iris.jpg

Why is the picture not filling the circle?

Comment: A pattern needs to be translated. In this case there is no need for pattern though, simply use drawImage to fill the arc (but there are several issues here, for example save/clip/restore, image is reloaded for each cycle etc etc)

Comment: I'll try to use drawImage later to fill the arc. thanks!